# Find duplicate item in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two unordered lists. One unordered lists get populated dynamically and you double click it's items to add to the other unordered list.

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the item on the dynamically populated list isn't already in the other list. If it is. then it shouldn't get added again. Don't want to add duplicate items.

The code that populates the ul:

```
.done(function(html) {
        var results = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
        $('#store_sel').children().remove();

            for (var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++){

                $("#store_selection").append("<li class='" + results[i].name + " stores'" + "id= " + results[i].uuid + 
                + ">" + results[i].name + "</li>");

        }      
    });
```

The event:

```
$('#store_selection').on('dblclick', 'li', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#store_selected').find($(this))) {
        console.log('item already there');
    } else {
        $('#store_selected').append($(this).clone());
        //$(this).remove();
    }       
});
```

EDIT: Why isn't this working? It basically goes to console.log even if the ul is empty.

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: You can identify them by `li` id, before you add

Comment: If you have a unique key, you can identify the duplicate values.
eg here if your unique key is `results[i].uuid`, you can check whether that record is already added or not

Comment: .find() doesn't return a boolean, you should check it's length: if($('#store-_selected').find($(this)).length <= 0))

Comment: @AndreasFurster I thought same but ids are different, one is selection second selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues within your `if` statement.

1. An element can't be in 2 places at the same time. Therefore you can't locate `this` in 2 lists
2. An object will always return truthy. Use `length` of returned selector collection instead

Since ID's must be unique in a page I suggest you use a `data-` attribute to store the UUID

```
<li data-uuid="xxxx-yyy">
```

Then when you search:

```
var uuid = $(this).data('uuid')
if ($('#store_selected').find('.stores[data-uuid='+uuid+']').length) {
    console.log('item already there');
} else {
    $('#store_selected').append($(this).clone());
    //$(this).remove();
}
```